# Android HttpURLConnection POST No data being sent

Tags: android, asp.net, json, post, httpurlconnection

I am running an ASP.net JSON service on localhost. I'm sending a JSON POST request from an Android app to the server. The server is receiving the connection, but no POST data (I confirm this by setting a breakpoint which hits after I POST from the Android app). The HttpURLConnection response code I get back is 200 OK. However, the data is not being received by the server. I am unsure as to whether any data is being sent. My android code is (wrapped in an AsyncTask):

```
public void makeHttpRequest(String verb, String serverAddr, String postBody)
    {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            serverAddr = "http://10.0.2.2:4617/parent/dummy";
            URL url = new URL(serverAddr);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Transfer-Encoding","chunked");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

            urlConnection.connect();

            out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            out.write(postBody.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("HTTP Response Code: " + responseCode + " | " + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException mal) {
            //
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            //
        }
        finally {
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch(IOException e) {

                }
            }

            if (urlConnection != null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

    }
```

The C#/ASP.NET service contract. instance of Parent is null, but should contain the data sent by POST:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestServiceParent
    {

        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "{dummy}", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        Parent PostParent(string dummy, Parent instance);
    }

public Parent PostParent(string dummy, Parent instance)
        {
            var result = MasterStorageStore.Instance.PostParent(instance);
            if (result == null) return emptyParent;

            return NewCopy(result);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out through a simple PHP script that for some reason despite setting `setRequestMode("POST")` and `setDoOuput(true)`, `HttpURLConnection` was being sent as `GET` instead of `POST`. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try adding a `out.flush();` after `out.write(postBody.getBytes("UTF-8"));`.

Comment: This results in a 400 Bad Request. Thanks, though.

Comment: Oh I just found that you didn't set request mode of urlConnection to "POST". Try `urlConnection.setRequestMode(“POST”);` before `connect()`. Not sure about that but maybe it will work.

Comment: That's what setDoOutput(true) does. I did try setRequestMode("POST"), but it didn't work.